# Authorize filter on Api Controllers - FormsAuthentication?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api

I have created my app and I have a **Application Controller** (base controller) where I force my authentication at all times. I can override this inside any derived controllers if needs be. I have an     [Authorize] attribute on this controller.

I have just started to create my **Api Base controller** which derives from my **Application Controller** to get access to Nhibernate Session, logger etc.

In my application, I make sure I set the FormsAuthentication like so:

```
        var cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(Name, false);
        var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);

        var expiration = DateTime.Today.AddDays(5);

        var newTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(ticket.Version, ticket.Name, ticket.IssueDate, expiration,
            ticket.IsPersistent, value.APIToken, ticket.CookiePath);
        var encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket);


        cookie.Value = encTicket;
        cookie.HttpOnly = true;

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Would the same thing be needed for my Api? Ideally I want to authenticate the user on each and every request with authentication provided via headers or query string e.g.

site.com/api/v1/projects?clientid=xxx&token=xxxxxxxxxxx

Requests to my Api Controller only work if I have the attribute:     [AllowAnonymous]

What is the best way to authenticate for my api calls?